# Lipshitz constant for $||Ax - b||_2^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

How to show that lipshitz constant for $||Ax - b||$, where A is a matrix and x, b are vectors, is given by $2 \lambda_{max} (A^T A)$. , where $\lambda_{max}$ the maximum eigen value.

So far, I have solved till

$$|| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y) ||_2\leq L ||x - y||_2$$

$2|| A^T (Ax - b) - A^T (Ay - b)||_2  = 2||A^T A (x - y)||_2  \leq 2\mathbf{||A^T A||} . ||x - y||_2$

In the last inequality , I am doubtful. Should the $||A^T A||_F$ occur or $||A^T A||_2$ should be there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need the $2$ norm of the matrix, see definition of this norm.

The last thing you need is that the norm of a matrix is equal to the maximum of all absolute values of all the eigenvalues. Since $A^T A$ is symmetric and positive definite all eigenvalues are real positive numbers. Hence the norm is equal to the maximal eigenvalue (witout absolute stripes)

Comment: Does it mean that the maximum eigen value of $A^T A$ should be the answer  and not the maximum eigen value?

Comment: $\lambda_{\max}(A^T A)$ means the maximal eigenvalue of $A^T A$.